# cant conver string to SimpleDateFormat

Tags: android, timezone, simpledateformat

I am using this code for on android just trying to convert string to date and represent it like I want.
my date looks like that:

```
 Fri, 23 Mar 2012 20:43:28 +0200
```

and the output that I want to get:

kk:mm dd/mm/yyyyy

I thinks my problem because time zone.
so if you can help me to fix it out.

the error is

```
 java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Fri, 23 Mar 2012 21:34:27 +0200" (at offset 0)
```

my code looks like that:

```
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss Z");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    Date date=null;
        date = format.parse(pubDate);
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what is your locale? Try with

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```